# Logout for twitter, linkedin and last.fm

Tags: php

I am able to log into my application with LinkedIn, Twitter and last.fm but on logout it logs out of the application and not LinkedIn, Twitter and last.fm. I want the user to log out of both LinkedIn, Twitter and last.fm and my application at the same time.
Please anyone suggest me how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? "Log out" how and where? The user? Why? What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't and can't log the user out of their sessions on the third party websites.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the various APIs is to permit your site to consume *their user's data*.

Your site has nothing at all to do with the rest of their site or service.

It would be objectively wrong if your site was *able* to log *their user* out of *their site*.

Or, put another way, short of giving the users links to log them out of the other sites, you can't do this.  And don't even *think* of trying to direct their browser at those URLs, you will make your users hate you.